# clang-format: empty line before and after control statements

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

Is there any possibility to achieve inserting an empty line before and after control statemets (for, if etc.)?

E.g. I have the following source code:

```cpp
if(bCondition)
{
    // some code
}
for(int i : vecOfInts)
{
    // some code
}
if(bAnotherCondition)
{
    // some code
}
```

and this is what I want:

```cpp
if(bCondition)
{
    // some code
}

for(int i : vecOfInts)
{
    // some code
}

if(bAnotherCondition)
{
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the official documentation, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html , there seems to be no such option.